# k3s cleanup of HelmChart?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have followed instructions from [this blog](https://blog.alexellis.io/test-drive-k3s-on-raspberry-pi/) post to set up a k3s cluster on a couple of raspberry pi 4:

I'm now trying to get my hands dirty with traefik as front, but I'm having issues with the way it has been deployed as a 'HelmChart' I think.

From the [k3s docs](https://github.com/rancher/k3s/blob/master/README.md)

> It is also possible to deploy Helm charts. k3s supports a CRD
>   controller for installing charts. A YAML file specification can look
>   as following (example taken from
>   `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/manifests/traefik.yaml`):

So I have been starting up my k3s with the `--no-deploy traefik` option to manually add it with settings. So I therefore manually apply a yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChart
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  chart: https://%{KUBERNETES_API}%/static/charts/traefik-1.64.0.tgz
  set:
    rbac.enabled: "true"
    ssl.enabled: "true"
    kubernetes.ingressEndpoint.useDefaultPublishedService: "true"
    dashboard:
      enabled: true
      domain: "traefik.k3s1.local"
```

But when trying to iterate over settings to get it working as I want, I'm having trouble tearing it down. If I try `kubectl delete -f` on this yaml it just hangs indefinitely. And I can't seem to find a clean way to delete all the resources manually either.

I've been resorting now to just reinstall my entire cluster over and over because I can't seem to cleanup properly.

Is there a way to delete all the resources created by a chart like this without the `helm` cli (which I don't even have)?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `kubectl delete -f` is hanging?

I had the same issue as you and it seemed like `kubectl delete -f` was hanging, but it was really just taking a long time.

As far as I can tell, when you issue the `kubectl delete -f` a pod in the `kube-system` namespace with a name of `helm-delete-*` should spin up and try to delete the resources deployed via helm.  You can get the full name of that container by running `kubectl -n kube-system get pods`, find the one with `kube-delete-<name of yaml>-<id>`.  Then use the pod name to look at the logs using `kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-delete-<name of yaml>-<id>`.

An example of what I did was:

```
kubectl delete -f jenkins.yaml # seems to hang
kubectl -n kube-system get pods # look at pods in kube-system namespace
kubectl -n kube-system logs helm-delete-jenkins-wkjct # look at the delete logs
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two options here:

1. Use the `--now` flag to delete your yaml file with minimal delay.
2. Use `--grace-period=0 --force` flags to force delete the resource.

There are other options but you'll need Helm CLI for them.

Please let me know if that helped.